# How can I test my module locally using a symlink?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run a module that I am developing on my local machine. So I have create a test nodejs application and within this test application I created the 'node_modules' director. The folder structure looks like it would if I had used npm install and specified my module as a dependency. Within the node_modules folder I have create a symlink to the directory where my module under test is.

When I attempt to run my test application node complains: Cannot find module 'my_module'.

I can figure out why this wouldn't work. Can this be done in this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for doing this is:

In your my_module directory, do `npm link .`. npm will tell you it has made my_module available for linking.

Then, in your test_app directory, do `npm link my_module`. npm will now make my_module available to your app.

Note that you can still get a a "cannot find module" error this way, but this is then most likely because your `my_module` module is structured wrongly. By default, Node.js will look for an `index.js` file in the module's root directory. Otherwise, you need to specify a `main` entry in the module's package.json, containing the path to your main js file, relative to the module's root directory.